# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

The second line is causing the exception listed below.  This code actually works on the test server, but is blowing up on my box. Can anyone offer a clue what I need to look at to solve this?

```
   TypedQuery<ed> _TypedQuery = _EntityManager.createQuery(_CriteriaQuery);
   List<ed>       _edList     = _TypedQuery.getResultList();
```

Exception

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1017) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:916) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1012) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:280) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl$SelectResult.load(SelectImpl.java:2381) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:274) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.InstanceResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(InstanceResultObjectProvider.java:60) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl$PackingResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(QueryImpl.java:2075) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:36) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1251) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1007) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:286) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302) ~[openjpa-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

Comment: When posting stack traces, always make sure to post the ENTIRE stack trace, even if you don't think it's necessary.  "Caused By" sections are very important. Also, we have no idea what `_CriteraQuery` contains, or the definition of the `ed` class (which should be `Ed` to conform to standard Java naming conventions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll document all my solutions to this problem.

- This is the 1st resolution.  The clue was [here](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Curious-if-this-stack-trace-is-familiar-td7516870.html.).  I upgraded Open
  JPA from 2.2.0 to 2.2.2 & the exception went away, so it appears that
  it was a bug.
- This happened again.  I was missing cglib.2.2.3.zip and/or
  cglib-nodep-2.2.3.jar.