# JPA, Open JPA OneToMany - FailedObject

Tags: java, jpa, junit, openjpa, apache-tomee

I am doing simple OneToMany JPA concept and verifying using Junit. Getting FailedObject error while getting entity ( oneToMany relation )
. am using Oen JPA latest version, TomEE 8.

**Post Entity**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", targetEntity = PostComments.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PostComments> postCommentsList;

  //Getter & Setter
}
```

**PostComments**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class PostComments {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    private String review;

    //Getter & Setter
}
```

**Service**

```
@Stateless
public class PostService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "movie-unit", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager em;


    public void addPost() {
        PostComments postComments = new PostComments();
        postComments.setReview("Success Review");

        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle(" Welcome");
        postComments.setPost(post);
        List<PostComments> postCommentsList = new ArrayList<>();
        postCommentsList.add(postComments);
        post.setPostCommentsList(postCommentsList);

        em.persist(post);

        System.out.println(" Post has been saved .........");
    }

    public List<Post> getPost() {
        System.out.println("###########"+em);
        int id = 1;
        Post post = em.find(Post.class, id);
        return Arrays.asList(post);
        //return em.createQuery("select e from Post as e").getResultList();
    }


}
```

**PostTest**

```
public class PostTest extends TestCase {

    @EJB
    private PostService postService;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        final Map p = new Properties();
        p.put("movieDatabase", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
        p.put("movieDatabase.JdbcDriver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        p.put("movieDatabase.JdbcUrl", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:moviedb");
        EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p).getContext().bind("inject", this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPost() {
        postService.addPost();
        List<Post> postList = postService.getPost();
        System.out.println(" postList = "+postList);
        assertEquals(1,postList.size());
        System.out.println(postList.get(0).getTitle()+" "+postList.get(0).getPostCommentsList().get(0).getReview());
    }



}
```

**JPA Query**

> INSERT INTO Post (id, title) VALUES (?, ?) [params=(int) 1, (String)
>   Welcome]
>
> PostComments (id, review, post_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>   [params=(int) 51, (String) Success Review, (int) 1]
>
> SELECT t0.title, t1.post_id,  t1.id, t1.review FROM Post t0 LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN PostComments t1 ON t0.id  = t1.post_id WHERE t0.id = ?
>   ORDER BY t1.post_id ASC [params=(int) 1]

**Exception**

> SEVERE - EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: null
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
>   FailedObject: 1 [org.apache.openjpa.util.IntId] [java.lang.String]    at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1029)   at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:923)    at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.find(DelegatingBroker.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:495)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.find(JtaEntityManager.java:224)
>     at com.demo.ex.service.PostService.getPost(PostService.java:41)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
>     at
>   com.demo.ex.service.PostService$$LocalBeanProxy.getPost(com/demo/ex/service/PostService.java)
>     at com.demo.ex.PostTest.testPost(PostTest.java:30)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)   at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)   at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)     at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.setInverseRelation(JDBCStoreManager.java:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initialize(JDBCStoreManager.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.initialize(DelegatingStoreManager.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.initialize(ROPStoreManager.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:1048)
>     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1006)
>     ... 46 more
>
> javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application
>   exception; nested exception is:   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
>   FailedObject: 1 [org.apache.openjpa.util.IntId] [java.lang.String]
>
> at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:447)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:351)
>     at
>   com.demo.ex.service.PostService$$LocalBeanProxy.getPost(com/demo/ex/service/PostService.java)

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure about `Post` id = 1? Might be another value

Comment: Yes, post id =1. SELECT t0.title, t1.post_id, t1.id, t1.review FROM Post t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN PostComments t1 ON t0.id = t1.post_id WHERE t0.id = ? ORDER BY t1.post_id ASC [params=(int) 1]

Comment: I mean in the database and not in the query

Comment: Yes,  INSERT INTO Post (id, title) VALUES (?, ?) [params=(int) 1, (String)  Welcome]
PostComments (id, review, post_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=(int) 51, (String) Success Review, (int) 1]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087792/org-apache-openjpa-persistence-persistenceexception-null)?

Comment: using latest version OpenJPA 3.0.0. that post has old version

Answer (score 0):

seems you didn't enhance your entities before running the code so some features are not fully functional: http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-maven.html

alternatively you can set openejb-javaagent on the test JVM (through surefire args you can pass -javaagent:/path/to/openejb-javaagent.jar like in http://tomee.apache.org/javaagent.html) which will do the same (bytecode instrumentation) but at runtime as in a plain tomee

side note: build time enhancement is recommended if you don't need to have this code portable accross multiple providers

Romain

Answer (score -1):

I have just tried the same code with Hibernate provider. it is working good. same code not working with Open JPA  :(

**Persistence.xml**

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>openejb-core-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That is not an ANSWER. It is extra info to add to your question